# Stop PHP_EOL from appending data to previous line

Tags: php, fwrite

I write data to a file using PHP with this format:

```
      fwrite($theFile, $theLine.PHP_EOL);
```

This works fine, but I'm including a new piece of code to remove blank lines:

```
      $theFile = "theFile.csv";
      $lines = file_get_contents($theFile);
      $lines = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "", $lines);
      file_put_contents($theFile, $lines);
```

This works great EXCEPT that when I go to save data the next time using this:

```
      fwrite($theFile, $theLine.PHP_EOL);
```

The data get written like this:

```
      write1     data1
      write2     data2write3     data3
```

I want the data to always be written like this:

```
      write1     data1
      write2     data2
      write3     data3
```

I've tried using "/n" and "/r/n" and so forth but nothing seems to work. The data always get appended to the previous line after all the blank lines have been removed.

I need a way to always put a line break ***IF*** the cursor is at the end of the previous line.

Comment: Have you tried `"\r\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL` just to check? You didn't mentioned if you're running windows/linux?

Comment: I tried this "fwrite($theFile, $theLine."\r\n");" and it made everything go on the first line (no line breaks at all). I'm on Windows OS but I think the server is Unix.

Comment: I have suspicion you might be opening the csv with excel? I've had my due nightmares with EOL and CSV. Instead of writing to file, echo the line instead  and set `header('content-type:text/plain');` as long as you have no other output on the page otherwise wrap it with a `<pre>` tag and browser should show the line break if it's there you can hopefully take it from there to resolve.

Comment: I switched to ```header('content-type:text/plain');``` and also made it a ```.txt``` file instead of .csv. I also opened the file with notepad instead of Excel. I'm still getting the issue - certain lines are appended rather than put on a new line. The erasing of the blank lines puts the cursor at the end of the previous line, so it thinks EOL is somewhere it isn't

Comment: It's not crucial that the blank lines be removed from the file. I can do that later. But it would be nice to have a way to check if the current "EOL" is actually empty or not, and then be able to write the data appropriately.